# batch: combine string operations

Tags: string, batch-file, operations

I'd like to combine the following string operations...

```
SET MYVAR=someStringWithSomeExpressionInside
SET MYVAR=%MYVAR:Expression=thing%
SET MYVAR=%MYVAR:~4%
```

...to something like this:

```
SET MYVAR=%MYVAR:Expression=thing~4%
```

**EDIT**

To give you an idea of what i'm intend to do:

```
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~8,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
SET TIMESTAMP=%TIMESTAMP: =0%
```

..this should be a single SET command without any helper variables.

Comment: what do you mean by combine?

Comment: something like %MYVAR:Expression=thing~4%

Comment: Please add this extra information to the question itself to help new viewers find it easily and more quickly understand your question, rather than having to read all the comments too.  This way your question quality will be improved.

Comment: You mean to perform the two dependent string substitutions in one shot. No its not possible, such a feature has not built into cmd syntax. each substitution has to performed sequentially as you did.

Comment: too bad :-( thx @sst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
set "MYVAR=someStringWithSomeExpressionInside"
set "MYVAR1=%MYVAR:Expression=thing%"
set "MYVAR2=%MYVAR1:~4%"
set "VAR=%MYVAR%%MYVAR1%%MYVAR2%"
echo %VAR%
```

or

```
set "MYVAR=someStringWithSomeExpressionInside"
set "VAR=%MYVAR%%MYVAR:Expression=thing%%MYVAR:~4%"
echo %VAR%
```

but sadly, as per you comment after I posted this. There is no single line replacement for multiple replace in batch.

Comment: no, i meant in a single expression like `%MYVAR:Expression=thing~4%` (without helpers)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value more reliable with wmic, only difference is that, without further string manipulation, the full year (YYYY) is given:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%t in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set stamp=%%t
```

I don't think there is a solution to combine multiple string operations in one command, but you can do something similar with for /f.

At first with the same result as above (YYYY-format):

```
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=,.:" %%a in ("%date%,%time%") do set stamp=%%c%%b%%a%%d%%e%%f
```

And here in the format you used in the question:

```
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=,.:" %%a in ("%date:~0,6%%date:~8,2%,%time%") do set stamp=%%c%%b%%a%%d%%e%%f
```

Here are all versions combined, creating equal output:

```
@echo off

SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~8,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
SET TIMESTAMP=%TIMESTAMP: =0%
echo #1=%TIMESTAMP%

for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%t in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set stamp=%%t
echo #2=%stamp:~2%

for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=,.:" %%a in ("%date%,%time%") do set stamp=%%c%%b%%a%%d%%e%%f
echo #3=%stamp:~2%

for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=,.:" %%a in ("%date:~0,6%%date:~8,2%,%time%") do set stamp=%%c%%b%%a%%d%%e%%f
echo #4=%stamp%

pause
```